# Deploy Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have been asked to make a few cosmetic changes to our production deployment. I have access to our linux box where I can see the files I need to change. I only need to change html.erb files, but when I add, for instance a simple `<p>` tag, it does not show up live.

I know I probably have to reset the server or redeploy the code, but I have no idea what to do.

Our production deployment is not fully live, so I am making changes on the fly (I know that this is not the best practice). Our app is running in a shared hosting environment for the moment.

I have seen threads where people use Capistrano to deploy but how? We do not currently use it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase someone is looking for the answer:

When rails is in development mode it will automatically reload changed files. When in production I need to restart it.

I eventually found out that we use God (A proces monitoring framework for rails - [link here](http://god.rubyforge.org/)).

I had to restart our app with the following command: 'god restart APP_NAME'

Hope that helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you make changes in production files, you have to restart the server to see the changes.
In production environment cache_classes is set to true. One can disable it and changes will be reflected without restarting the server.
So to reflect the change restart the server.

thanks......

Comment: Thanks Anubhaw- I made a change then went to the console and restarted using 'sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart'. The server restarted successfully, but my change is still not showing up live. Any other ideas?

Comment: see you are making changes in the right code set...... for ex. remove all some code from html file and check if it reflects or not.... thanks.....

Comment: I just removed an entire table from a view, deleted cache on my browser and viewed the page but the table is still there. I know I am looking at the correct piece of code and the correct app deployment. I can freely change static html pages in the /public directory and these are changing fine.

Comment: Check if the server you are using has some caching mechanism on... I cannot think of any other reason other than mentioned above....

Comment: If you are making changes in the console, are you using the right rails environment. `rails console production` or `ruby script/console production` for example. Without specifying the environment, the console will default to development.

Comment: It is likely that nginx isn't actually serving the Rails code, but acting as a frontend for an application server such as Unicorn.  You may need to restart that server not nginx.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good guide on the [Capistrano github wiki](http://help.github.com/capistrano/) and also used [this guide @ kris.me.uk](http://kris.me.uk/2010/08/30/rails3-hosting-all-in-one.html) about a complete rails setup, including the Capistrano deployment aspect. I used them when learning how to deploy rails apps effectively. They should tell you what you need to know to get a basic deployment setup up and running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter but I am not looking for a quick win right now- I will look into those tutorials later.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Capistrano // NGINX guide and posted it on my blog. It's 85% correct, and should help you understand the big picture of the server/Rails/SSH configurations.

http://westonplatter.com/blog/2012/08/19/rails-slash-nginx-rackspace-deployment/